# How can I access a resource file string and display in my .chtml page?

Tags: c#, string, model-view-controller, resources

I have a resource file called **Resources.resx** and I want to access a string inside the file called **appDisclaimer** with some text.

How can I access this string and display in my .cshtml view page?
Example:

```
 <footer>my disclamer... </footer>
```

Comment: I found some answers here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047272/mvc4-localization-accessing-resx-from-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the question linked in my comment:

```
<footer>@NSResources.Resource.appDisclaimer </footer>
```

**NSResources** is the Namespace
**Resource** is the File name
**appDisclaimer** my string