# Access Resources.resx file within Properties folder from razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

From a view cshtml in my ASP.NET MVC app I am trying accessing a string in my Resources.resx file without success.

The Resources.resx file is within Properties folder:

MyProject -> Properties -> Resources.resx

It has the following properties set:

```
Build Action: Embedded Resource 
Custom Tool: PublicResXFileCodeGenerator
Custom Tool Namespace is not set (left blank)
```

Also in Resources Designer in Visual Studio on the top I have changed the combo Box value for Access Modifier from internal to Public. But it still not working....

From my view cshtml I import the resoureces:

```
@using MyCompany.MyProject.Resources
```

and then I use below syntax:

```
@Resources.MyLabel
```

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047272/mvc4-localization-accessing-resx-from-view) but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved by importing the correct namespace:

```
@using MyCompany.MyProject.Properties
```

instead of:

```
@using MyCompany.MyProject.Resources
```